# iOS simulator need to test myapp with Word App can I do this?

Tags: ios, emulation

I have an app(myapp) which interacts with MS Word app.  I've tested this on devices but also wanted to test devices I did not have on the simulator.  I did not find any way to do this but wanted to confirm here.  I would need to a) be able to run the simulator with the MS word app installed b)run with xcode and myapp(which I can do now).  Everything I read said, no can do:<  Please let me know if I"m mistaken!
Thanks,
Kate

Comment: No, because you can't get an x86 simulator build of Word

Comment: Do you have an iOS device available to you? Install the Word app on there and build your app onto the device.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is installing MS Word. Commercial apps are pre-built for ARM-based real devices, and not available for the simulator. You would need an X86 version of the MS word app built for the simulator, and unless you have contacts at Microsoft that's probably not available.

(BTW, it's a simulator, not an emulator.)